# VB.NET Tab Control pause drawing while changing tabs

Tags: vb.net, drawing, tabcontrol

I have a tab control with 5 tabs on it.  Each tab has a large number of individual controls on it.  (Ranging from 3 to 70 controls, all standard checkboxes, textboxes, comboboxes and radiobuttons.)

When running, the drawing seems to freeze mid-way through changing tabs.  So you end up with part of the old tab's controls along with part of the new tab's controls drawn together.

I'd like to be able to stop drawing until all the controls are fully loaded and the code has finished running the "scoring" code.

I have tried using Suspend/Resume Layout on both the tab control and individual pages, but it does not seem to have any affect on drawing.

I have also tried using a custom class I found while searching for an answer, but it either doesn't pause the drawing or it causes the form to become unstable visually.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Friend Class DrawingControl
    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Boolean, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Const WM_SETREDRAW As Integer = 11

    Public Shared Sub SuspendDrawing(ByVal parent As Control)
        SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, False, 0)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub ResumeDrawing(ByVal parent As Control)
        SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, True, 0)
        parent.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

*** EDIT 11/22/2019: Adding the "Scoring" code that runs when changing tabs

Here is the sequence of events that run when changing tabs:

1) TabControl Deselecting

```
Private Sub tabDetails_Deselecting(sender As Object, e As TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles tabDetails.Deselecting
    tabDetails.SuspendLayout()
    pgAcademic.SuspendLayout()
    pgBusiness.SuspendLayout()
    pgLIS.SuspendLayout()
    pgPatient.SuspendLayout()
    pgRegulatory.SuspendLayout()
End Sub
```

2) TabControl Selected - No code here - However, it's after THIS that the tabs become "combined" with the outlines of controls from each tab.

3) TabControl Index Change

```
Private Sub tabDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tabDetails.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim pg As Integer = Me.tabDetails.SelectedIndex
    Select Case pg
        Case 0
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgPatientCare
        Case 1
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgBusiness
        Case 2
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgLIS
        Case 3
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgAcademic
        Case 4
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgRegulatory
    End Select
End Sub
```

4) Step 3 fires this code:

```
Private Sub UpdateScore()
    Dim intTotalScore As Integer = Vars.intNewScore  'Max Score = 708
    Dim intScore As Integer = 0

    If Vars.DisableEvents Then Exit Sub
    Vars.DisableEvents = True

    score_pgPatientCare = Scoring.UpdateScore(Me.pgPatient)
    score_pgBusiness = Scoring.UpdateScore(Me.pgBusiness)
    score_pgLIS = Scoring.UpdateScore(Me.pgLIS)
    score_pgAcademic = Scoring.UpdateScore(Me.pgAcademic)
    score_pgRegulatory = Scoring.UpdateScore(Me.pgRegulatory)

    intTotalScore += (score_pgPatientCare + score_pgBusiness + score_pgLIS + score_pgAcademic + score_pgRegulatory)

    Using dbTPT As New BGL_ApplicationsEntities

        '** Use this area if needing to calculate more than YES/NO

        '**********************
        '***  Patient Care  ***
        '**********************
        If chkPatientCare_IRB.Checked Then
            If Not txtPatientCare_IRB.Text.Trim = "" Then
                Dim propertyName = "PatientCare_IRB_Approved"
                intScore = CType(weightSettings.Items.Item(propertyName), Integer)
                score_pgPatientCare += intScore
                intTotalScore += intScore
            End If
        End If

        '**********************
        '***    Business    ***
        '**********************
        If chkBusiness_Replace.Checked Then
            If chkBusiness_Outdated.Checked Or
                chkBusiness_Inferior.Checked Or
                chkBusiness_Savings.Checked Then
                intScore = 0
                Dim propertyName = "Business_Replace_Just"
                intScore = CType(weightSettings.Items.Item(propertyName), Integer)
                score_pgBusiness += intScore
                intTotalScore += intScore
            End If
        End If
    End Using

    ssLabel.Text = "Total Score: " + intTotalScore.ToString
    custProgBar.Value = intTotalScore

    Dim pg As Integer = Me.tabDetails.SelectedIndex
    Select Case pg
        Case 0
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgPatientCare
        Case 1
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgBusiness
        Case 2
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgLIS
        Case 3
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgAcademic
        Case 4
            Me.txtPageScore.Text = score_pgRegulatory
    End Select

    Vars.DisableEvents = False
End Sub
```

5) The above code fires this code for each tab:

```
Module Scoring
    Public Function UpdateScore(ByVal tab As TabPage) As Integer
        Dim intPgScore As Integer = 0
        Dim intScore As Integer = 0
        Dim intMult As Integer = 0
        Dim arrPropName() As String
        Dim strPropName As String
        Dim strYesNo As String = Nothing

        'If Vars.DisableEvents Then Return 0
        'Vars.DisableEvents = True

        Using dbTPT As New BGL_ApplicationsEntities
            If tab.Name = "pgPatient" Then
                For Each pan In tab.ChildControls(Of Panel)
                    If pan.Name.ToString.Substring(0, 6) = "chkgrp" Then
                        Dim cuScores() As Integer = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
                        Dim i As Integer = 0
                        For Each chk As CheckBox In pan.ChildControls(Of CheckBox)
                            If chk.Checked Then
                                arrPropName = Split(chk.Name.Replace("chk", "").Replace("CU", "PatientCare"), "_")
                                strPropName = arrPropName(0) + "_" + arrPropName(1)
                                Dim w = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.Weight_Name = strPropName)
                                If w IsNot Nothing Then
                                    intScore = CType(frmNewProject.weightSettings.Items.Item(arrPropName(0) + "_" + arrPropName(1)), Integer)
                                    intMult = CType(frmNewProject.weightSettings.Items.Item(arrPropName(0) + "_" + arrPropName(2)), Integer)
                                    cuScores(i) = intScore * intMult
                                End If
                            Else
                                cuScores(i) = 0
                            End If
                            i += 1
                        Next

                        For Each txt In pan.ChildControls(Of TextBox)
                            txt.Text = cuScores.Max.ToString
                        Next

                        intPgScore += cuScores.Max
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            For Each chk As CheckBox In tab.ChildControls(Of CheckBox)
                intScore = 0
                arrPropName = Split(chk.Name.Replace("chk", ""), "_")
                If Not arrPropName(0) = "CU" Then
                    If chk.Checked Then strYesNo = "_Yes" Else strYesNo = "_No"

                    strPropName = arrPropName(0) + "_" + arrPropName(1) + strYesNo
                    Dim w = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.Weight_Name = strPropName)
                    If w IsNot Nothing Then
                        intScore = CType(frmNewProject.weightSettings.Items.Item(strPropName), Integer)
                    End If
                End If

                intPgScore += intScore
            Next

            For Each rad As RadioButton In tab.ChildControls(Of RadioButton)
                intScore = 0
                arrPropName = Split(rad.Name.Replace("rad", ""), "_", 2)
                strPropName = arrPropName(0) + "_" + arrPropName(1)
                If rad.Checked Then
                    Dim w = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.Weight_Name = strPropName)
                    If w IsNot Nothing Then
                        intScore = CType(frmNewProject.weightSettings.Items.Item(arrPropName(0) + "_" + arrPropName(1)), Integer)
                    End If
                End If

                intPgScore += intScore
            Next

            For Each cbox As ComboBox In tab.ChildControls(Of ComboBox)
                intScore = 0
                If cbox.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
                    If cbox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        intScore = 0
                    Else
                        strPropName = cbox.Name.Replace("cbox", "") + cbox.SelectedValue
                        Dim w = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.Weight_Name = strPropName)
                        If w IsNot Nothing Then
                            intScore = CType(frmNewProject.weightSettings.Items.Item(strPropName), Integer)
                        End If
                    End If

                    intPgScore += intScore
                End If
            Next
        End Using

        Return intPgScore

    End Function
End Module
```

6) Selected tab is painted

```
Private Sub Paint_Tab(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles _
        pgAcademic.Paint, pgBusiness.Paint, pgLIS.Paint, pgPatient.Paint, pgRegulatory.Paint

    tabDetails.ResumeLayout()
    pgAcademic.ResumeLayout()
    pgBusiness.ResumeLayout()
    pgLIS.ResumeLayout()
    pgPatient.ResumeLayout()
    pgRegulatory.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be more useful to know what happens when you switch TabPage (any code related to the TabPage selection?). Possibly, a better description of what *large number* means, what type of controls you're using (3rd-party?), if you're loading data, bitmaps etc. performing some sort of drawing, using background images, accessing storage units on a network etc.

Comment: Try putting your `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` calls in the `TabControl`'s  [`Deselecting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.deselecting) and [`Selected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected) handlers, respectively.

Comment: @Jimi I have updated the question to include all the code that runs, and the number & type of controls being used.  None of them are 3rd party.  There are no bitmaps or other background images being loaded - only controls.

Comment: @InteXX Selected fires BEFORE the tab is actually drawn.  Instead I tried to use the Paint handler since that is fired last.  Either way, Suspend/Resume Layout doesn't do anything for drawing the controls.

Comment: I see. You might want to rethink your UX.

Comment: @JQSOFT Sorry I've been away for a while.  I did consider using a background worker, but that won't work because I am dealing with controls.  Controls are a part of the UI and can't be touched by the background worker... Unless you know something I don't?  I know it's a lengthy routine, but it was the only thing I could come up with to get the scoring.  If you have any ideas, I'm open to hear them.

Comment: @InteXX  I am not sure what you mean.  Updating the User Experience how, exactly?  The current layout I have is how the users want to see/use the application.  Not sure what I would change.

Comment: They may opt for a modified layout that you would propose, if they're faced with a decision to reduce the number of controls displayed at one time so as to eliminate performance lags. That's a lot of controls for one view. Subtabs maybe? This discussion might be a good one for [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Here's a thought: Implement `Async/Await` to free up the UI and use `Progress(Of T)` in your worker code for control updates.

Comment: @JQSOFT  Thanks for the links.  I was able to take some of that and implement it, partially.  I was able to create a backgroundworker (bw) for a piece of code when the form loads.  However, I have not been able to figure out how to get it to work with the scoring.  When trying to add a bw to step 4 above, I get errors with the combobox in step 5.  I think I need to do more research on backgroundworkers as I have never really used them.  If you have any ideas on how to add it to my code above, please share.